# Azure Offline Sync Pulls Nothing

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have had nothing but issues with getting this offline sync client running. Now it isn't pulling anything and I cannot for the life of me figure out why! Here is my sync code on the client:

```
    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
     {
        if (!App.MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
        {
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
            store.DefineTable<clist>();
            await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());
        }

        await SyncAsync();
        await RefreshNcards();

    }
    private async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        String errorString = null;
        PullOptions pageSize = new PullOptions { MaxPageSize =1000 };

        try
        {
            await LocalCards.PullAsync("clist", LocalCards.CreateQuery(),pullOptions:pageSize); // first param is query ID, used for incremental sync
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorString = "It look's like we weren't able to make sure your cards were updated. No worries, next time you start the app we will try again. This won't impact your experience.";

            //    errorString = "Pull failed: " + ex.Message +
            //      "\n\nIf you are still in an offline scenario, " +
            //      "you can try your Pull again when connected with your Mobile Serice.";
        }

        if (errorString != null)
        {
            MessageDialog d = new MessageDialog(errorString);
            await d.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

This code pauses for a few seconds than moves on with no errors thrown. Here is my class:

```
    class clist : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_createdAt")]
    public DateTime _createdAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_updatedAt")]
    public DateTime _updatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_version")]
    public DateTime _version { get; set; }
    public bool _deleted { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Nid")]
    public string Nid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Nname")]
    public string Nname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Nset")]
    public string Nset { get; set; }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case its helpful here are the log streams I get when I run logging in the Azure Portal.

2016-04-13 04:36:05 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=d9ceb9a8-433f-4a23-a4ab-3caf984cb8e8 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522131849 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 914 1625 11874
2016-04-13 04:36:26 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=159b6aa0-df2e-46a8-8a24-d0a0086acdaf 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522152216 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 584 1626 20039
2016-04-13 04:36:46 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=e7c12e75-54a8-4be3-9e66-7399635657f6 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522164231 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 584 1625 20065
2016-04-13 04:37:06 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=c78b53c1-15d8-491b-8c6b-22d8239fd920 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522184449 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 584 1625 20027
2016-04-13 04:37:26 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=a5e45861-bedd-4162-bc88-373306825e85 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522204509 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 584 1625 20052
2016-04-13 04:37:46 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=90f17ac1-2516-4bf8-ba9b-470fa1bf7748 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522224587 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 584 1625 20023
2016-04-13 04:38:06 ~1MAGICHUB POST /dev/api/events/wwwroot/longpoll X-ARR-LOG-ID=f715514e-f0aa-4299-950a-88b1884d89bf 443 - 172.103.28.93 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2486.0+Safari/537.36+Edge/13.10586 ARRAffinity=6910fd768a90c2d11e23085af4d93c48a8cc9617be87c545bc1e82b0186ea1da;+__RequestVerificationToken=ded78fdc-d9b2-49ad-bb5b-3a791b4a6886;+ai_user=3MLsg|2016-04-13T03:47:20.208Z;+ai_session=R6FJD|1460519240333|1460522244667 https://magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/tables/clist.js magichub.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 584 1625 20056
2016-04-13 04:38:13 MAGICHUB GET /tables/clist $filter=(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.0000000%2B00%3A00')&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=1000&__includeDeleted=true&$filter=(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.0000000%2B00%3A00')&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=1000&__includeDeleted=true&X-ARR-LOG-ID=c6b2681c-2dbe-4452-8c49-367343c36655 443 - 172.103.28.93 ZUMO/2.0+(lang=Managed;+os=Windows+Store;+os_version=--;+arch=X64;+version=2.0.31125.0) - - magichub.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 695 1286 93

I am completely stumped as to why this is not working and would be stoked if anyone could help me narrow down the culprit and get this working!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors in your model.

The system properties need to be called `createdAt`, `updatedAt` - these don't have underscores any more.  The `version` field should be a string - not a DateTime.  The Id field should be capitalized.

You are relying on PullAsync performing the cache push for you.  You should really be explicit about that and do PushAsync().

You didn't provide the definition of LocalCards, but make sure it is an instance of `IMobileServiceSyncTable<clist>` - obtained by `client.GetSyncTable<clist>()`.

Comment: If you start with the Todo list quickstart in the Azure Portal, you'll have a working sample that you can then tweak with your particular data model. 

I also recommend using Fiddler or adding a logging handler to help debug your requests, see [this sample LoggingHandler]( https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs#L63).